# Join two tables and convert rows in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table 1

```
    date1    | id  | t_code | ac_code |  value | kt_id  |
-------------+-----+--------+---------+--------+--------+
 2021-05-07  |  13 | AF12   | #BT8    |    1   | 11201  |
 2021-05-07  |  13 | AF12   | #BT8    |    1   | 11201  |
 2021-05-07  |  13 | AF12   | #BT8    |    2   | 11208  |
 2021-04-08  |  13 | SH11   | #GS5    |    3   | 11201  |
 2021-03-15  |  15 | TG53   | #BA7    |    1   | 11207  |
 2021-03-11  |  17 | AF12   | #BT8    |    2   | 11208  |
 2021-03-11  |  14 | AF15   | #BT5    |    2   | 11209  |
```

Table 2

```
    date2    | id  | t_code |  value | kt_id  |
-------------+-----+--------+--------+--------+
 2021-05-07  |  13 | AF12   |    5   | 23201  |
 2021-05-07  |  24 | TB39   |    1   | 23203  |
 2021-05-07  |  13 | AF12   |    2   | 23208  |
 2021-04-08  |  13 | AF12   |    3   | 23201  |
 2021-03-11  |  15 | TG53   |    1   | 23207  |
 2021-03-11  |  28 | AK21   |    2   | 23208  |
```

I want to join this both tables with an inner join. The on Condition should be contains the date (date1, date2). Furthermore I will convert lines in colums. This means, I want only select on the kt_id the id's 11201 (as typ_1) and 11208 (as typ_2) and sum up the values of them.
In the table 2 I want only select on the kt_id the id 23201 (as typ_3). The "id", "t_code" and the date should be the same.

So I want to get follow result:

```
    date     | id  | t_code | typ_1  | typ_2 | typ_3 |
-------------+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+
 2021-05-07  |  13 | AF12   |   2    |   2   |   5   |
 2021-04-08  |  13 | TB39   |   3    |   0   |   3   |
```

How can I solve this with a sql query?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you need, given the explanation.  Use a `SUM CASE`.

EDIT: Query now flattens the data in a `CTE` from both tables before joining, so that it doesn't fan out in a man-to-many situation and inflate the values.

```
;with t1
as (select date1, id, t_code, kt_id, sum([value]) as [value]
    from table1 
    group by date1, id, t_code, kt_id)
    , t2
    as (select date1, id, t_code, kt_id, sum([value]) as [value]
        from table1 
        group by date1, id, t_code, kt_id)

select t1.date1, t1.id, t1.t_code,
        sum(case when t1.kt_id='11201' then t1.[value] else 0 end) as typ_1,
        sum(case when t1.kt_id='11208' then t1.[value] else 0 end) as typ_2,
        sum(case when t2.kt_id='23201' then t2.[value] else 0 end) as typ_3
from t1
join t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
    and t1.t_code = t2.t_code
group by t1.date1, t1.id, t1.t_code
order by t1.date1, t1.id, t1.t_code
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I insert the where clause to limit the result, for example:
`where t1.id = 13 and t1.t_code = 'AF12' `
I get too high values for typ_1, typ_2 and typ_3

Comment: I've edited the query above to manage in case there are multiple matches across both tables.

Comment: We can't solve it with just one query, can we?

Comment: That is one query. It's a common table expression (CTE).  See more about them here https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/

Comment: thank you, the query fits well. I only have one additional request. I would have to filter the table two for rt_value = 0. Only applies to table two. rt_value column has only two values, 1 and 0. I only want to select to 0.
I have implemented it, but I do not get any values ​​for the column typ_3.
`.... , t2
    as (select date1, id, t_code, kt_id, rt_value, sum([value]) as [value]
        from table1 
        group by date1, id, t_code, kt_id, rt_value).....

AND t2.rt_value = 0 ....`